# How do I store radio button selection in my DB with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, mongoid, mongodb

I am using Rails 3 and Mongoid.

I am able to store text fields and select fields but can't seen to figuer out how to store a radio option in the DB whe the form is submitted. Here is my code...

**Model**

```
class Somerandomname
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :name
    field :option   
end
```

**Controller**

```
  def create
    @somerandomname = current_user.somerandomnames.new(params[:somerandomname])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @somerandomname.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@somerandomname, :notice => 'Somerandomname was successfully created.') }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
<%= f.label :name , "Name:" %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>


<%= radio_button_tag(:option, "option1") %>
<%= label_tag(:option_option1, "option 1") %>
<br />
<%= radio_button_tag(:option, "option2") %>
<%= label_tag(:option_option2, "option 2") %>
```

What do I need in my model and controller file in order to capture the selection into my DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your view to:

```
<%= f.label :name , "Name:" %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>


<%= f.radio_button(:option, "option1") %>
<%= f.label(:option_option1, "option 1") %>
<br />
<%= f.radio_button(:option, "option2") %>
<%= f.label(:option_option2, "option 2") %>
```

That will cause the generated input fields to have the proper @name namespaced within :somerandomname.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a field called option in your model. And in your controller you could do

```
model.option = params[:option]
model.save
```

depending on what radio button is selected the value of params[:option] will be set (to the value of the selected radio button).

Comment: I'm not getting it to work. I'm going to edit my original questions to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

As far as parameters go, radio buttons are just like checkboxes: they all have a parameter name and a value that they send through when checked.  The only difference is that a particular group of radio buttons uncheck each other when checked, so that only one of them can be selected.

So, in your example you would have a field called 'option' in your db table, which would be set from params[:option] which would be equal to either "option1", "option2" or "option3".